# VB Help Needed Regarding DateAdd Function

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB script. I am trying to execute a script whereby if a date field is not blank then a value will be returned which equates to the value of the date field in question +2 days. Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
If {APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp} = ""  THEN
ReturnValue = DateAdd("d",2,now)
ELSE ReturnValue = DateAdd("D",2,{APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp})
ENDIF
```

Comment: Not sure why your else statement uses the DateAdd Function? In either case here is the examples: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. I am trying to say if the date field is blank then use current date +2days otherwise use value of the field +2days.

Comment: Should I not use the ELSE function?

Comment: is this VB .Net or VB Script (VBA)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If IsDbNull(APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp) THEN
   ReturnValue = dateadd(DateInterval.Day, 2, Now)
ELSE 
   ReturnValue = dateadd(DateInterval.Day, 2, APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp)
ENDIF
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for feedback....I get an 'Expected Statement (line 5)' alert when I check the syntax

Comment: Hi Justin. Which exactly is the Line 5?  Is the value of APP1.DM_Project(1) a DATETIME field or string? Also, I'm supposing APP1 is a database field and because of this I utilized IsDbNull...

Comment: Hi David, from what I can see it is the ENDIF statement. I can confirm the field is a DateTime field.

Comment: End IF and not ENDIF

Comment: Thank you...I have corrected this and I now get an alert saying 'Object required: 'APP1'(line 1)'

Comment: The following syntax executes successfully:
If {APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp} = ""  Then
ReturnValue = DateAdd("d",2,now)
else
ReturnValue = {APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp}
end if

Comment: Its just when I try to add the 2 days to the value of the field after ELSE.

Comment: Is the ReturnValue variable a Datetime type?

Comment: Is the "{" character to denote an Array? Is so, you must select one of these values only, not the entire array...

Comment: Hi David, Its a date/calendar drop down in the CRM so I am assuming it is a DateTime field rather than a string

Comment: I drag the field from the available table fields on the left onto the CRM page and it concatenates the field in the syntax window as {APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp} denoting table and field

Comment: hope this helps? Appreciate your patience

Comment: Certify the returned value is *really* a datetime type value. Use DEBUG to stop in the IF and put the cursor over APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp.  You will see its value and type.

Comment: And if someone wants to participate of StackOverflow is mandatory has the enogh patience to help others; isnt't it?   :)

Comment: Hmmm.... Reading the old posts I wonder: isn't lacking a .VALUE instruction? Something like:  APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp.value or {APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp}.Value ?

Comment: You can also try CDATE({APP1.DM_Project(1).EndTaskDateExp}.Value) to ensure it will be a DATE variable type.